# Sum of 4 first index $\sum_{n=1}^4a_i=1$

Tags: calculus, index-notation

$\sum_{n=1}^4a_i=1$
The meaning of this sum, means that:
*$a_1=1, a_2=1, a_3=1, a_4=1$
OR:
*$a_1=1, a_2=2, a_3=3, a_4=6$

Or something else?

Comment: No, it means that the sum $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 1$. E.g. $a_1 = 0, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 0, a_4 = 0$ would fulfill that.

Comment: @СССР Hi, Thanks for the answer.
So it means that?:
If i=1: a1=1.
if i = 2: a1+a2=1
if i=3: a1+a2+a3=1? and such on till i=4?

Comment: Not quite. See my comment with an example above. The $i$ is only an index, it goes from 1 to 4 here. The values of the elements labeled by those indices are what are being summed.

Comment: Oh I see... but its quite problematic. since if i=1, then a1=1 should be 1, its not a contradiction to it? or if i=1 or if i=2, then they does not relate to each other, its seprated for each situation

Comment: If its not a contradiction, then I think I got it, if they dont relate, so I see why what you say is understandable.

Comment: The index $i$ is just a label. It doesn't say how many terms your sum contains. It only corresponds to one specific element. So you were almost right in your reply above except  it's not $i = 1$ or $i = 3$. It's e.g. $i$ runs from 1 to 1, $i$ runs from 1 to 3, etc.

Comment: I see, thanks alot!!
I was on a debate on a friend, turns out we both were wrong hehe, I thought the first option, he thought the second one ( we thought about it for like 20min, not in a row, but today at class ). Thank again for clearing it out for us :) ( EDIT: if you want, you can make an answer so i can approve it and do V to the answer )

Comment: Nevermind about the answer, glad I helped.